# How can I run python code on Mobile devices

Tags: python, machine-learning, signal-processing

I have developed one Machine learning model in Python. I want to run it in mobile device.

This model require Xgboost machine learning algorithm few signal processing library to extract signal features.

I don't want to perform training on mobile, but just testing the model.

What I tried so far

1. ML Kit - This is Google service. But issue is it usage tensorflow. No support for Xgboost
2. Core ML -  Specifically for iOS. But signal processing support is not available
3. Treelite - We can convert the model into C. But C code does not have feature extraction. I have tried to do feature extraction in C, Java but required signal processing packages I could not find or implement in.

Checked out various other links and articles but no support.

If any possible way to run python packages directly on mobile device, that can save my life.

Comment: did you find some convenient solutions?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you Pythonista. 
It works fine and there is almost everything what you want. You can't really use every module but still many and it cost 10$... 
Sadly it's only available for iOS: 
Click [here](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/pythonista-3/id1085978097) to open it from the App Store. 
Click [here](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/index.html) to take a look for the official page.

Here are some pros and cons:

**Pros:**

- Syntax highligthing
- many modules (Probably even the full library, but I haven't tried that yet)
- Example Files (How to use the sensors, etc.)
- Official docs: http://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/
- (half-) full Autocomplete

**Cons:**
 - not very suitable on small screens

PS: 
If I missed something: Feel free to edit it :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This looks interesting. Have you used it before? How can I run my existing python code using pythonista?

Comment: Well I have it on my mobile but I don't use it very often, because I code only little projects on my phone xD. There are multiple ways, how to run your existing python code! You can put your code in iCloud or Google Drive! You could even run code from the internet (if I have understood it right) directly without downloading it, which is pretty funny :D

Comment: On cloud it is already running, I want to create offline version of this same code. So any advice to run it offline is much helpful

Comment: Just add it to your files (on your mobile) or copy your code in a file of your mobile (Sorry, I haven't got that much experiences with this app xD)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [xgboost-predictor-java](https://github.com/komiya-atsushi/xgboost-predictor-java), Just adding the dependencies in android studio. 
It takes your model as an input and uses for prediction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in that case I will require to create model in Java. For that I have to perform feature extraction in java, where feature extraction require signal processing which is not available in java code